# Density of $G$-invariant morse functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a compact manifold $M$. Let $f$ be a  $G$-invariant smooth function. Can it be approximated by $G$-invariant Morse functions?

Comment: Approximated in which topology?

Comment: any of the standard ones.(eg compact open etc). if there is an approximation please mention the topology

Comment: Compact-open is just uniform convergence here. The other natural topologies are $C^1$, etc.

Comment: So  you are saying there is a approximation in these topologies C^{1} uniform convergence etc. Please give a reference.

Comment: Where did you read that I said this?

Comment: This is just a suggestion. (From what I just read) the proofs that smooth functions can be approximated by Morse functions rely on embedding the manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then constructing an explicit Morse function (i.e. Proposition 1.2.5 here https://stanford.edu/~sfh/morse.pdf) using the distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In your case you can pick a invariant metric and an equivariant embedding in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to some linear group action by the equivariant Nash embedding theorem. So I guess you could just try to "make the proof equivariant"?

Comment: @NickL What role does the metric play in your suggested argument? It seems to me it only calls for a differentiable embedding, rather than an isometric one. One can then refer to the Whitney embedding theorem - and avoid the result of Nash -, for which there apparently exists an [equivariant version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostow%E2%80%93Palais_theorem).

Comment: You are right, this version of the equivariant Whitney embedding would be enough (if everything works which I haven't checked)

Comment: For reference, it seems to me that Lemma 4.8 in Wasserman's 'Equivariant Differential Topology' answers the question in the affirmative.

Comment: thanks a lot sirs